# knitr - function that works both in \Sexpr and in code-chunks

Tags: knitr

I try to learn *knitr*.

*knitr* lets you nest snippets of "inline-code" written in the language *R* between `\Sexpr{...}`.

*knitr* lets you nest "code-chunks" written in the language *R* between

```
<< >>=
[chunk of R-code goes here]
@
```

. knitr does pre-process the input-file. Hereby all snippets of inline-code and all code-chunks are processed by the language *R*.
In what is fed to (La)TeX the  snippets of inline-code and the code-chunks are replaced by the result of this processing.

I try to write an *R*-function which does a system-call, e.g., `echo some phrase` and captures the standard-output and delivers into the .tex-file created by *knitr*.

By now I have an *R*-function for doing this within *R*-code-chunks and another function for doing this within *R*-`\Sexpr`-inline-code-snippets.

The function to be used within  *R*-code-chunks does not work out within *R*-`\Sexpr`-inline-code-snippets.

The function to be used within  *R*-`\Sexpr`-inline-code-snippets does not work out within *R*-code-chunks.

The question is:

What should an *R*-function for *knitr* look like which works out both within  *R*-`\Sexpr`-inline-code-snippets and within *R*-code-chunks?

Here is the file **test.Rtex** I have so far:

```
<<CallExternalFunctionsStuff, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results='asis'>>=
knitr::opts_template$set(
  CallExternalApp = list(include=TRUE, cache=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results='asis')
)
CallExternalAppInChunk <- function(A) {
  return(cat(paste(system(A, intern = TRUE),collapse="\n")))
}
CallExternalAppInSexpr <- function(A) {
  return(paste(capture.output(cat(system(A, intern = TRUE), sep="\n", fill=FALSE)), collapse="\n"))
}
@
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent Between ZZZ is what \verb|verbatim| does usually:\bigskip

ZZZZ
\begin{verbatim}
hello1
hello2
\end{verbatim}ZZZZ

\bigskip

\noindent \verb|CallExternalAppInChunk| works inside an R-code-chunk:\bigskip

ZZZZ
\begin{verbatim}
<<opts.label='CallExternalApp'>>= 
CallExternalAppInChunk("echo hello1&&echo hello2")
@
\end{verbatim}ZZZZ

\bigskip

\noindent \verb|CallExternalAppInSexpr| works inside knitR's \verb|\Sexpr|:\bigskip

ZZZZ
\begin{verbatim}
\Sexpr{CallExternalAppInSexpr("echo hello1&&echo hello2")}
\end{verbatim}ZZZZ

\bigskip

\noindent \verb|CallExternalAppInSexpr| does not work inside an R-code-chunk:\bigskip

ZZZZ
\begin{verbatim}
<<opts.label='CallExternalApp'>>= 
CallExternalAppInSexpr("echo hello1&&echo hello2")
@
\end{verbatim}ZZZZ

\bigskip

\noindent \verb|CallExternalAppInChunk| does not work inside knitR's \verb|\Sexpr|:\bigskip

ZZZZ
\begin{verbatim}
\Sexpr{CallExternalAppInChunk("echo hello1&&echo hello2")}
\end{verbatim}ZZZZ

\end{document}
```

Here is the output this produces

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short answer is that you return the character string but mark it with `xfun::raw_string()`, e.g.,

```r
CallExternalApp <- function(A) {
  xfun::raw_string(paste(system(A, intern = TRUE), collapse = "\n"))
}
```

Under the hood, `xfun::raw_string()` will let R's `print()` function [print a string with `cat()`](https://github.com/yihui/xfun/blob/e7af6826c408063591a58c2f82b07e04853e60db/R/data-structure.R#L82-L85), which makes it work in a code chunk, and also return the string itself (with a new class), which makes it work in an inline expression in `\Sexpr{}`.

In a code chunk, R objects are automatically printed (this is [a subtle feature of R](https://yihui.org/en/2017/06/top-level-r-expressions/)). In an inline R expression, **knitr** obtains its returned value and writes it out unless the value is marked as `invisible()`.

Why doesn't `CallExternalAppInChunk()` work in `\Sexpr{}`? Because it doesn't return the character value, but returns what `cat()` returns (i.e., an invisible `NULL`).

Why doesn't `CallExternalAppInSexpr()` work in a code chunk? Because it returns a normal character string, and **knitr** will print it in the way that a character string is printed in a normal R console (i.e., with indices like `[1]` and double quotes).

Comment: When using `CallExternalApp` within a code chunk nested within a `verbatim`-environment, the `verbatim`-environment in the .tex-file produced by **knitr** contains an additional trailing empty line. This trailing empty file yields visible vertical space in the .pdf-file. I don't have this additional trailing empty line when in the code chunk using `CallExternalAppInChunk`.  Please forgive me for lacking the experience in dealing with R to be able to track all this.

Comment: One way to avoid the extra empty line is remove both the `verbatim` environment and the chunk option `results='asis'` and then add the chunk option `comment=''`. Then **knitr** will generate the `verbatim` environment for you. But I guess you won't like the default shaded environment. If that's the case, you can set the background to white via the chunk option `background='white'`. (No worries about your experience with R; I'm happy to help!)